# Add a single image field to a view (not its nodes, the view itself)

Tags: views, entities, theming, media

I would like to know if it is possible to have an image field in the setup of a view, that I could then display in front-end, on top of the view via the views-view template.

So far, I can only find topics about how to add an image field to nodes of the view. I want this image field to be related to the view, just like the "view title" field.

Answer (score 1):

Views are all about rows of data. To achieve what you want, you have two options:

1. Create `.tpl` file for your view, put `<img>` tag in it
2. Attach view to a node using, for example, [Viewfield](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module. In that node create image field you want.

First option is faster, second one allows easier image changes.

Comment: The problem with the first solution is that it is not user-friendly, and I am not the one who will administer the views after. That is why I need a nice image field on the options of the view. And then as you say, I will apply the image field (if set) on the view via the views-view template. Will look up the second solution though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use the views header, like so:

Header: click Add

Select Entity: Rendered Entity

select entity type, and entity ID

then give the relevant users access to that entity / node

Comment: Quite opposite to my answer - I suggested to attach view to node, you - to attach node to view. I must admit, your solution needs one less module up and running.

Comment: I thought maybe it would be nice to have the change flow into the view wherever it currently exists in the site, without changing any of its containers. I'm lazy that way.

Answer (score 0):

Fields are attached to entities, and views are not entities.

All you can do is to relate a view with any entity type that provides such a field ([beans](https://drupal.org/project/bean) sounds more appropiate than nodes). It can be done by several means, some of them outlined in the other answers here.

AFAIK there's no module that eases/automates this task. I think it would be a very handy module.

Comment: I acknowledge this fact indeed. I just felt a bit frustrated because there are already fields to a view that the user can fill in. (ie the title of the view, the number of items per page, etc.) Just no way to add any other field, sadly.